# cannot post in axios in vue.js

Tags: javascript, axios

I have try this code

```
axios
    .post("http://localhost:3010/user/login", {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: "username", password: "password" })
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.resp = response;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

but response it invalid login but it work in postman

[image]

What wrong with it?

in web response like this

[image]

Comment: Why not just do a simple `axios.post("http://localhost:3010/user/login", { username: "username", password: "password" })` and let Axios and Laravel handle the headers and JSON.

Comment: Why are you setting the `Content-Type` and why are you `stringify`ing?  Pretty sure axios sends as JSON by default.  I'm guessing that it thinks you are sending an actual "String" and not a JSON Object.

Comment: looks like you've got data and options mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you send an object using post, it gets converted to a string, so what you're effectively sending to your API endpoint is:

```js
JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({ username: "username", password: "password" }))
```

there is no need for that

Also, you don't send a body as part of the headers.

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

what that means in your case is that you send three arguments, url, then data and then the options. Since the only header you send is that it is json data, and axios can take care of that for you, the options in this case are not needed so you can use just the first two parameters

```js
axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:3010/user/login",
      {
         username: "username",
         password: "password" 
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.resp = response;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change headers
**From**:

```
headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }
```

**To**

```
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}
```

Now try, It worked for me